# Chrome Extension to replace <input> types

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension to find password fields and automatically enter my password. This is my current code. However, it can't seem to find the password types. What am I doing wrong, guys?

```
window.addEventListener("load", get_passwords, false);
function get_passwords() { 
    var node_list = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var textboxes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < node_list.length; i++) {
        var node = node_list[i];
        if (node.getAttribute('type') == 'password') {
            textboxes.push(node);
        }
    } 
console.log(textboxes);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is where you are trying to access value in a couple of places where it is not the proper thing to do

```
var node_list = document.getElementsByTagName('input').value;
```

should be

```
 var node_list = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
```

Your alert also has the same problem.

[Here is a fiddle of the code I wrote to get this working.](http://jsfiddle.net/vnLBQ/1/)  Use your debugging tools and the problem becomes quite obvious

Comment: Okay, I get it. But if I use alert instead of console.log, I still get [HTMLInputElement]. I don't get how I can go to the <input> and insert a value there. Man, this is complicated.

Comment: You need to make this be more robust to deal with if more than one box is found and other things but basically change the log to textboxes[0].value = "MyPassword" http://jsfiddle.net/vnLBQ/3/   You seem to be lacking some basic understanding of the objects your are modifying.  You should try to understand the pieces better as that step is logical if you understand that.